# Upper bound for set of vertices intersecting all triangles in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I want to know if there have been studies regarding the minimum set of vertices intersecting all triangles in a graph.

This is a particular case of feedback vertex set, in which we want to intersect all cycles in a graph. There is a famous conjecture of Albertson and Berman (*M. O. Albertson and D. M. Berman, A conjecture on planar graphs. Graph Theory
and Related Topics, Academic Press 1979*), which states that at most half of its vertices suffices to intersect all cycles in a graph.

What I asking also can be seen as a vertex variation of a problem that asks for a set of edges intersecting all triangles in a graph. For this, there is a famous conjecture of Tuza which relates this parameter to its natural dual.

I want to know if there are similar conjectures, when we want is a set of vertices intersecting all triangles.

Comment: Search for: *minimum vertex cover in 3-uniform hypergraph*

Comment: Thank you. In terms of hypergraphs, the most studies are about Ryser Conjecture. As I understand, in terms of graphs, this implies that for 3-partite graphs, a vertex-transversal is at most twice the size of a packing of triangles. I want to know if there is a related conjecture which not impose the fact that the graph is 3-partite (or r-partite in the general conjecture of Ryser.)